# Installed GFCI outlet,outlet only had one black wire and one white,other outlets have ground,neutral,and hot.outlet tester showing open ground

Tags: electrical

How to fix other outlets showing open ground on outlet tester. Install GFCI outlet, on outlet with only neutral and hot wire. No ground.

Comment: Are the connections via cable or conduit?  Are the boxes made of metal? Are you testing the outlets while they are mounted on the boxes, or loose?  How old is the wiring?  Any chance you can add photos?   Please [edit] the question to add info and clean up grammar.

Comment: You could just edit the first one https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/265551/18078 rather than asking it again. Still needs a bit more clarity, and ideally some clear pictures of the (breaker off) receptacles pulled out of the box, but wires still connected.

Comment: good thing it's a GFCI, they make a ground less important for safety.

Answer (score 1):

If the incoming wires are in a cable then if it is relatively recent (not sure how long, but at least the last 30 years) there should be a ground wire in the cable, but sometimes it is not brought all the way into the box. Alternatively, if there is metal conduit or certain types of other cable then there will be ground automatically when everything is connected together, *including screwing the GFCI/receptacle into the box*. So check for wires but also check that ground status when the GFCI/receptacle (and the other receptacles) are in place, not hanging out.

If all else fails, you can *retrofit ground* by running just a ground wire (green or bare) from the receptacle to another grounded location (another receptacle, breaker panel, a junction box that has a good ground, etc.).

And if that is not practical, then for an *existing* location (can't do this for new stuff) you can label the GFCI/receptacle (and all "load" connected receptacles) **no equipment ground**. The safety gets provided by the GFCI (in most situations where the ground wire would be of use, the GFCI will trip). There are still some advantages to having a proper ground wire, but this helps *a lot*. However, this is only valid for pre-existing locations (i.e., moving up from "no ground, no GFCI" to "no ground but with GFCI"). It is not valid for new receptacle locations and you absolutely must not replace a 2-prong receptacle with a 3-prong receptacle unless you are able to properly connect ground or install GFCI. You don't need GFCI at each receptacle - proper use of "load" is fine. But you do need a label at each receptacle. For the GFCI-protected receptacles (except the one with the GFCI) you should also add a "GFCI protected" label, though arguably that isn't necessary unless the circuit requires GFCI protection (kitchen, basement, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

If it is ungrounded Romex, you would have to run a ground to it somehow. It does not have to return to the electrical panel; it needs to be grounded somehow.I found a great resource from InspectAPedia: [2-Wire (no ground) Electrical Outlet Wiring](https://inspectapedia.com/electric/Electrical_Outlet_2-Wire_Connections.php#Other)

Comment: If the OP is installing a GFCI, ground is _nice_ but not _necessary_.